# How to make conditional statement in WpBakery (formarly Visual Composer)

Tags: customization, visual-editor, authentication

I am building a new membership website with WordPress using WpBakery (formally visual composer).
I created a heading text which I linked to my login page, everything works fine but the problem is that I want to replaced the login text with logout once user is authenticated (that is, when user is no longer a visitor).
Is there anyone with better idea on how to do this.

Comment: The WordPress function you'd need is is_user_logged_in(), if that's accessible from wherever you can configure this.

Comment: As to whether it's supported or not though it might be worth asking them directly.